# Обстоятельство места в предложении

Tags: синтаксис, порядок-слов

Дано предложение: "Он заблокировал её в Facebook". "В Facebook" ─ это ведь обстоятельство места? Но тогда почему не "В Facebook он заблокировал её"? Потому что "в Facebook" поясняет слово "заблокировал"?

Answer (score 2):

Потому, что в данном случае такой порядок более естественный и понятный.
Да, есть очень много наблюдений и рекомендаций в отношении порядка слов в русском языке, но они имеет главным образом статистический характер, конкретные же примеры обычно поддаются вполне законченному анализу на примитивном уровне, без углубления в академические дебри.

Начнем с того, что "в фейсбук" весьма условное обстоятельство места, фактически оно здесь - обычное дополнение. Разница в том, что не действие произведено в фейсбуке, а прямое дополнение там находится заблокированным.

Сравните: "Он обнаружил жену в постели" и "В постели он обнаружил ошибку в доказательстве". В первом случае в постели находится субъект, во втором - объект. Замените - на "её" и вы быстро поймете разницу.

Иногда порядок определяет акцент. Аналогичный пример "В ящике он обнаружил письмо" и "Письмо он обнаружил в ящике". В первом случае акцент на "ящике" - ну вот открыл и нашел письмо, во втором искал письмо и нашел именно в ящике.

Однозначно можно говорить о безразличии порядка и заодно - обстоятельстве места, слов только когда оба - объект и субъект там находятся ("Он заблокировал её в дверях" и "В дверях он заблокировал её") - но и тут есть вполне ощутимый акцент.

В отношении фейсбука можно трактовать и так и эдак. И акцент смещается, и в указанном месте находится только объект, по отношению к субъекту это не так очевидно. Но естественным выглядит порядок при котором "место" идет и после глагола и после объекта. Иначе возникают какие-то акцентные связи (то ли важно что именно её, то ли именно в фейсбуке, то ли вообще кто именно заблокировал), лишающие фразу нейтральности.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Фраза считается нейтральной, если сообщает просто о факте блокировки и не содержит никаких акцентов?

Comment: @IgorGovorushko  Да, примерно. Когда нет оснований выделять какое-то слова в качестве более важного. .   .

Answer (score 1):

Обычно используют прямой порядок слов: подлежащее, сказуемое, дополнительные члены.

**Он заблокировал её в Facebook**

Другие варианты тоже возможны, например как у Вас:

**В Facebook он заблокировал её**

Подробнее, вот что пишет о порядке слов [Розенталь](http://rosental-book.ru/styli_xlii.html):

В русском языке порядок слов (точнее, порядок членов предложения) считается свободным. Это значит, что в предложении нет строго закрепленного места за тем или иным его членом. Например, предложение, состоящее из пяти знаменательных слов: Редактор вчера внимательно прочитал рукопись – допускает 120 вариантов в зависимости от перестановки членов предложения.

Различаются   п р я м о й   п о р я д о к   слов, определяемый типом и структурой предложения, способом синтаксического выражения данного члена предложения, его местом среди других слов, которые  непосредственно   с  ним   связаны,   а  также   стилем   речи   и  контекстом,   и   о б р а т н ы й 
п о р я д о к,  являющийся отступлением   от  обычного  порядка  и  выполняющий  чаще всего  функцию 
и н в е р с и и,  т. е. стилистического приема выделения отдельных членов предложения путем их перестановки. Прямой порядок характерен для научной и деловой речи, обратный широко используется в произведениях публицистических и литературно-художественных; особую роль обратный порядок играет в разговорной речи, имеющей свои типы построения предложений.

Определяющим фактором расположения слов в предложении является целенаправленность высказывания, его коммуникативное задание. С ним связано так называемое а к т у а л ь н о е ч л е н е н и е   высказывания, которое предполагает движение мысли от известного, знакомого к неизвестному, новому: первое (основа высказывания) обычно заключено в начальной части предложения, второе (ядро высказывания) – в его конечной части. Ср.:

1) 12 апреля 1961 года состоялся полёт Ю. А. Гагарина в космос, первый в истории человечества (исходной точкой, основой высказывания является указание на дату, т. е. сочетание 12 апреля 1961 года, а ядром высказывания – остальная часть предложения, которая логически подчеркивается);

2) Полёт Ю. А. Гагарина в космос, первый в истории человечества, состоялся 12 апреля 1961 года (основой высказывания является сообщение об историческом полете Ю. А. Гагарина, а ядром высказывания – указание на дату, которое логически подчеркивается).

Comment: Это понятно. Но не подумает ли кто-нибудь, прочитав "Он заблокировал её в Facebook", что "в Facebook" логически подчёркивается (то есть подчёркивается, что именно в Facebook, а не где-то ещё)? У меня цель другая: просто сообщить в предложении о факте блокировки.

Comment: Прямой порядок слов - самый нейтральный из всех возможных. Я бы его оставил. В первую очередь сообщается, что он ее заблокировал, затем уточняется, что в Facebook. Например во фразе "В Facebook он заблокировал её" подчеркивается Facebook и как-бы подразумевается, что в других сетях он предпринял (или не предпринял) другие действия.

Answer (score 1):

Порядок слов действительно связан с актуальным членением (известное – новое) и определяется **коммуникативной целью**, но по одному этому предложению цель определить трудно, не хватает информации, нужен контекст.

Примеры:

1) Пусть она напишет ему в Facebook. – **В Facebook (известное) / он ее заблокировал (новое).**

2) Как ему написать? Он везде ее заблокировал. – **Он её заблокировал (известное) / в Facebook (новое)**, а  в других социальных сетях не блокировал.

Comment: Но предложение "Он заблокировал её в Facebook" без всякой дополнительной информации, скорее всего, будет понято просто как сообщение о факте блокировки, разве нет?

Comment: Ваша учетная запись в Facebook заблокирована. Это вариант простого сообщения о факте блокировки, используется стандартный порядок слов: группа подлежащего и сказуемое. В вашем же случае сообщение делается для собеседника и должно строиться как ответная реплика.

Comment: Почему как ответная реплика? Я хочу послать вам SMS: Иванов заблокировал Петрову в Facebook.

Comment: Здесь-то  всё ясно: Иванов, Петрова. А вот если Вы используете личные местоимения "он, она", значит,  обращаетесь к кому-то, продолжая начатый диалог. Простое сообщение о факте тогда уже не получится. Тогда уже стройте предложения по коммуникативным правилам.

Comment: ..или монолог. Иванов и Петрова поссорились. Он заблокировал ее в Facebook.

Comment: Или монолог, или любой контекст, поясняющий ситуацию и определяющий  "известное и новое".  Вообще говоря,  если наши пользователи понаблюдают за тем, как они интуитивно строят свою речь, то могут убедиться, что свободный порядок слов - это МИФ, в русском  языке  позиция  каждого слова что-то выражает: или  нейтральность сообщения,  или его коммуникативный характер.

Comment: Согласен с каждым словом!

Comment: @Sibylla Пусть у нас не "он" и "она". Допустим, речь идёт о конкретных людях: "Я заблокировал мистера N в Facebook". Если я правильно вас понял, такое предложение (без каких-либо уточнений) будет понято как просто сообщение о факте блокировки. Я прав?

Comment: Да, такое предложение имеет стандартный порядок слов, и его можно считать сообщением о факте блокировки. Другое дело, что это "не просто сообщение", так как оно всё равно имеет какую-то коммуникативную цель (как и всякое сообщение), и эта цель может быть разной: 1) Начало разговора:"Я заблокировал  N в Facebook". - Да, а почему? 2) Продолжение разговора: Тебе N прислал своё сообщение? - Я заблокировал  N в Facebook, поэтому он ничего мне прислать не может.